# Iperius - бекап выполнен с ошибками (out of memory)

Tags: windows, резервное-копирование, ram, outofmemoryerror

Процесс iperius.exe постепенно выедает всю ОЗУ на сервере в процессе бекапирования. В связи с этим - бекап выдаёт ошибку 'out of memory'. Чем можно это исправить или ограничить его аппетит?

Comment: Кажется, это в техподдержку iperius

Comment: Вообще, хитрые проги для бэкапа (не скрипты дёргающие 7z) с дедубликацией и инкрементностью ОЧЕНЬ любят оперативу. Особенно при первом запуске. Так что тут 2 варианта: докинь плашек, используй bat\sh + 7z. Ну это при условии, что не из-за глюков проги, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась после назначения процессу низкого приоритета и выдачей только одного ядра ЦПУ